# Redirect URI for authentication

Tags: api, redirect

We are integrating our Salesforce with one of the third party application and they are asking us to provide our Redirect uri (where they will send the token once authenticated). Im not sure what needs to be provided here. Do I have to create a public API and then provide them a link of the endpoint as 'Redirect URI'?

Sample: https://clientapi.xxxx.com/api/oauth/?resp_type=code&**redirect_uri={uri}**&client_id={id}

Comment: Have you set up a Connected App in Salesforce for the purpose of integration?

Comment: Yes, I have created a Connected App but again, im not sure how does that help? Our partner (one of the third party app providers) are asking us for our redirect URI. Does SF provide a redirect uri that I can provide them?

Comment: try defining an auth provider and use the callback url from the auth provider in your redirect param,  your connected app should list this auth provider callback url in the Callback URL. Use your Connected App Key and Secret in creation of the connected App in order to generate the callback URL

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, as you are using a Connected App for the integration with the third party app, the **redirect_uri** in this case is the **Callback URL** as configured in the Connected App being utilized. Refer more on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm), added a reference image for the respective value from the Connected App settings.

[image]